# Why are deleted questions still visible to some users?

Tags: support, questions, deleted-questions, privileges

I have seen some users referring to *deleted questions*. So, a deleted question is still visible to some users.

Why is it so? Is it a **bug** or a **privilege?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[It is a privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). Users with at least 10k rep are allowed to view deleted questions (as long as they have a URL to the question).

From the privilege description page:

> ### Viewing deleted posts
>
> You now have privileged access to posts that have been removed, either
>   by their authors, by users with access to moderator tools, by
>   moderators, or by the system.
>
> Use this privilege wisely:
>
> - Make sure what is being deleted should have been deleted, and bring unnecessary or harmful deletions to the attention of the community
>     and/or moderator team.
> - Watch for signs of abuse being obscured by deletion.
> - Don't abuse this privilege to stir up trouble when someone has wisely decided to remove a problematic post.

Comment: Users with any amount of reputation can also see their own deleted posts; [recently deleted posts are listed for convenience in one's profile](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645/159251).